# MFC Ribbon app not displaying ribbon - when .exe is copy pasted to a different machine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, ribbon

Well, I am facing a strange problem. I have developed a sample MFC ribbon application on my machine - Windows 7 , with Visual Studio 2008. When I copy paste the .exe onto my laptop and run the app , I don't see the ribbon menu (in fact the app has not menu now) .

I have tried looking up the .dll that load in each case(on my work machine and laptop) using process monitor but I am unable to locate what I might be missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1 -

Ok, So thanks for your responses. Some progress has been made with this issue

1. I changed my IDE to VS 2010. The ribbon was coded manually and I figured out if I could add it as a resource maybe the problem would be solved. VS 2008 did not have the option of adding a ribbon as a resource.
2. I installed the VS 2010 Service Pack Redistributable X86/X64 depending on whether the machine is 32 or 64 bit.
3. I built a new "ribbontest.exe" app from VS 2010 and deployed it on other machines on which I would test my actual app. The ribbon for "ribbontest.exe" loads without any problems.

**When I deploy my app and run it, first the old menubar loads for a sec or two, then the ribbon flashes and disappears.**

A little history of the app I am referring to - 
Initially my application had the menubar view. I followed this article http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c14929/MFC-Feature-Pack-An-Introduction.htm  to accommodate a ribbon.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your laptop running Windows 7?

Comment: The ribbon control's xml is loaded by a  MFC dll, off hand i forget which one vc 08 used to do this with, without that dll the ribbon will fail to load the ribbon and other resources.

Comment: Manifest is a part of application in the app’s resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there's a conflict in the settings 'paths'. In your `InitInstance()` handler, you've got a statement like this:

```
// Standard initialization
// If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
// of your final executable, you should remove from the following
// the specific initialization routines you do not need
// Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
SetRegistryKey(_T("yourappname"));
```

If you haven't changed that name yet, do it. If you did, open `regedit.exe` on your target machine and remove the whole key under `HKCU\Software\yourappname` and then try again.

MFC stores user customizations of Ribbons/Menus/... under that key. But if you changed your app those settings don't necessarily match anymore and you can end up with stuff not showing correctly or not at all.

Comment: This is not correct. Application creates this key on the first run and close, saving setting. This registry entry has nothing to do with Eternal Learner problem.

Comment: It can have: if the key wasn't changed from the default that sample apps use, and he tried another sample app on that computer already. Then there might be wrong settings in there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download and install the Visual C++ Redistributable Runtime on your destination machine: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

Or, something like it.  Make sure you have architecture (x86/x64) correct and make sure it matches with the service pack version you compile with.

Comment: Joe, the application would not even open on the target machine without the c++ redistributable on the machine

Comment: @johnathon Yet after saying this, you tell him to look for an MFC DLL in the thread above? The VC++ runtime installer installs MFC. In general, MFC apps don't call LoadLibrary() but rely on straight dynamic linking. If he was missing a DLL in this manner, it would say which one is missing. He may not have the right version of the DLLs he needs.

Comment: Just to clarify:
LoadLibrary is used to load DLL and ask for procedure address. It is called explicit dynamic linking (dynamic load or run-time dynamic linking).

This allows using library without linking with import library and need for a header files.
 
When you link module using import library (.lib) LoadLibrary is not necessary; library is loaded automatically. This is implicit dynamic linking (static load or load-time dynamic linking).

Answer (score -1):

**Joe is right:** you need redistributable.

**Joe is right:** you cannot run 64-bit program on 32-bit machine.

All of the above would be indicated by the system (missing DLL, configuration incorrect, or 64/32 bit discrepancy)

**Joe is right:** your application must be built for specific set of minimum Windows version and service pack.

In addition to Joe’s post you must run release build not debug build.
If all of those requirements are met and you still have this problem, try linking MFC statically and see if problem persists.